# Передать На вторую форму значение label

Tags: c#, winforms

При нажатии на ячейку открывается новая форма, где должен отобразиться текст `label`:

> info.label11.Text = "gfgfg";

```
info info = new info();
if (e.RowIndex == 0)
        {
            info g = new info();
           g.Show();
            {
                info.label11.Text = "gfgfg";
            }
```

Но передача не осуществляется, `label` остается пустым.

Как правильно передать значение `label` в программе?

Comment: label должен меняться на начальной форме или на создаваемой?

Comment: @Tivyram на создаваемой

Comment: Вы создаете 2 экземпляра info() меняете label у первого, но отображаете второй. И label может попробуете поменять до отображения формы?

Comment: g.label.Text = info.label11.Text;

Comment: @NickProskuryakov а где сам передаваемый текст писать?простите,я просто запутался совсем/

Comment: @Tivyram info() это форма.а info.label11 является ссылкой.попробовал перед открытием формы записать в label но все так же

Comment: @Андрей строкой info.label11.Text = "gfgfg"; вы присвоили значение для label на форме info, далее при открытии новой формы вы задаете значение текста label на второй форме равное значению на первой форме. допишите после вашей строки мою, поправив имя label в моем примере.

Comment: @NickProskuryakov ступил по началу)все сделал,спасибо вам!